# MLB rules for blown save and win by same pitcher

Tags: baseball, mlb

In the Major League Baseball, does a relief pitcher who blows the save in the top of the 9th inning also get credit for the win when his team comes back in bottom of the 9th for the win?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's quite possible and happens with some regularity.

Kenley Jansen of the Dodgers recorded both a win and failed to record a save even though he entered the game eligible for one when pitching for the Dodgers on [Sunday, April 21, 2019](https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/MIL/MIL201904210.shtml).

In 2012, [Fangraphs](https://blogs.fangraphs.com/proposed-rule-change-blown-save-wins-revert-to-the-starting-pitcher/) wrote an article suggesting that the rule be changed so that relief pitchers could not benefit from this situation quite as much.

Comment: In fact, it's one example of why the win stat for pitchers isn't really reflective of the pitcher's performance. You don't want your regular closer to have a lot of wins: it often means he's blowing a lot of saves.