# Does a relief pitcher who loses the lead then regains it get a win?

Tags: rules, baseball, pitching

Starting pitcher ends inning with a 3-1 lead.  New inning, relief pitcher gives up two runs for a 3-3 tie.  Bottom of that inning we go ahead and finish with a win. Which pitcher gets the W?  Seems odd if the relief pitcher who blows the lead would get the W.

Comment: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/21330/mlb-rules-for-blown-save-and-win-by-same-pitcher

Comment: There is an exception that "a relief pitcher who is
ineffective in a brief appearance" does not have to be awarded the win, even if their team takes the lead while they are pitcher of record.  However, I think "brief appearance" usually means something like 0 or 1 outs; if they pitched a full inning, even if badly, this normally wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 5):

[Rule 9.17(a)](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf) states:

> The Official Scorer shall credit as the winning pitcher that pitcher whose team assumes a lead while such pitcher is in the game, or during the inning on offense in which such pitcher is removed from the game, and does not relinquish such lead
>
> [ some exceptions which don't apply here ]

The relief pitcher in your example meets that definition, so they are the winning pitcher. What you're finding here is that wins and losses for pitchers aren't a very good measure of very much at all.

As an aside, as the relief pitcher entered the game in what was a save situation (a lead of no more than 3 runs) and failed to keep the lead, they would be "credited" with a blown save in this example. However, saves are probably an even less meaningful statistic than wins and losses.